# Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> com.thelastpickle.tlpstress.PartitionKey]

Tags: java, cassandra, codec

I am running a stress test of LWTs in Cassandra using tlp-stress (http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/10/31/tlp-stress-intro.html). When I run the below command it errors out.

```
bin/tlp-stress run LWT -d "2m" --replication "{'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-east': '3', 'us-west-2': '3'}" -t 10 --host 10.xxx.xxx.xxx

Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> com.thelastpickle.tlpstress.PartitionKey]
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> com.thelastpickle.tlpstress.PartitionKey]
```

I am not a developer and does not know java, need help to figure out what's wrong here and what should be done to make it run? does it need any java drivers to be installed? I only download the tlp-stress as mentioned in the link, I am able to run other basic tests with this tool though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that they are trying to save or read text data into object of class that doesn't have corresponding mapping in Java driver. Because the other tests work, then all drivers, etc. are setup correctly.  I think that this is simple error in the code, and you can open the [issue on Github](https://github.com/thelastpickle/tlp-stress/issues).

Comment: Thanks Alex, will do.